# Why search suggestion only shows previously searched terms when using ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4

Wether Magento 2.3 or 2.4 (with ElasticSearch), the searchbox seems to display suggestions only for previously searched terms.

I've configured ElasticSearch 7.6, cron, did the reindex and flushed caches a few times, but it doesn't bring any suggestion, unless for terms I have searched and pressed [enter].

[image: I've searched for erin before]
[image: Never searched for tank]

(Above example using sample data)

Is there a way to pre-populate the suggestions, based on search-able attributes?

Answer (score 0):

@ricardo currently there is no such functionality you are requesting is out of the box.

but you can easily achieve by adding some extension

I can suggest on extension which is widely use in community is

https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite